# Determine the following function whether it is injective or surjective.

Tags: functions

Determine the following function whether it is injective or surjective.
$$f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$$
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$

Comment: To start off, what's the domain and range? Is it $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: This can only be answered if domain and codomain of the function are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

(1) For any $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;x^2+y^2\neq-1\;$

(2) $\;f(1,1)=f(1,-1)\;$